# JSON increases Float32Array buffer size many folds when sending through websocket

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket, arraybuffer, typedarray

I got a strange experience. When I send data of this arraybuffer setting:

```
var f32s = Float32Array(2048);
for (var i = 0; i < f32s.length; i++) {
    f32s[i] = buffer[i]; // fill the array
    ws.send(f32s[i]);
}
```

The buffer size I got at the other end is 8192 bytes.
But when I send chunck of buffer in JSON format like bellow:

```
var obj = {
    buffer_id: 4,
    data: f32s[i]
};
var json = JSON.stringify({ type:'buffer', data: obj });            
ws.send(json);
```

The buffer size I got at the other end bloat to **55,xxx** bytes with data filled in and **17,xxx** bytes with no data filled.

Why this happen and how do I keep the buffer size low?
I want to do this because the stream is choppy when I render it at the other end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this is happening because a float 32 array requires exactly 32 bits per number within the data structure, however json being an ascii format represents each number with a serious of 8bit characters, and then another 8bits for the comma and maybe again for the decimal and again for the delimiting whitespace.

Therefore the data `[0.1234545, 111.3242, 523.12341]` for instance requires 3 * 32 => 96 bits to represent within a float32array but as a json string requires 8bits for each of the 32 characters in this example which comes to 256 bits.

Comment: I don't quite understand this though, but imaginable. Is there anyway to compress Float32Array without data lose?

Comment: A Float32Array will use 4 bytes per item no matter what you do. However you can efficiently compress the data for transmission by enabling gzip compression on the server.